# Is this the correct way to load plugins in Guice?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I'm using Guice for DI and am trying to load modules in a plugin style.
Imagine I have a `UserProvider` and it expects a `IDataSource`. The `IDataSource` can be a `DatabaseDataSource` or a `LdapDataSource`, but not both (Doesn't make sense to have 2 sources of truth at the same time, does it?). Then I'm going to choose the `IDataSource` using a class name string loaded from a configuration in a file (eg, the deployment folks can configure which data source to use).

I have laid out the code as such

```
guice
   |- + user
      |- + datasource
         |- + database
            |- DatabaseDataSourceConfig.java
            |- DatabaseDataSource.java
            |- DatabaseDataSourceModule.java
         |- + ldap
            |- LdapDataSourceConfig.java
            |- LdapDataSource.java
            |- LdapDataSourceModule.java
         |- IDataSource
      |- UserProvider.java
      |- UserProviderConfig.java
      |- UserProviderModule.java
   |- Factory.java
   |- FactoryConfig.java
```

Factory.java

```
public class Factory {
    public static UserProvider create(FactoryConfig settings) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(
                new AbstractModule() {
                    @Override
                    public void configure() {
                        bind(FactoryConfig.class).toInstance(settings);
                    }
                },
                (Module)Class.forName(settings.getUserProviderModuleClassName()).newInstance());

        return injector.getInstance(UserProvider.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // simiulate building config from file
        String modClass = "guice.main.user.UserProviderModule"; // or a stub that doesn't hit the data source
        String subModClass = "guice.main.user.datasource.ldap.LdapDataSourceModule";
        Config config = ConfigFactory.empty()
                .withValue("user.module", ConfigValueFactory.fromAnyRef(modClass))
                .withValue("user.dataSource.module", ConfigValueFactory.fromAnyRef(subModClass));

        FactoryConfig factoryConfig = new FactoryConfig(config);
        IUserProvider provider = Factory.create(factoryConfig);

        provider.work();
    }
}
```

FactoryConfig.java

```
public class FactoryConfig {
    private interface Keys {
        String USER_PROVIDER_MODULE = "user.module";
        String USER_PROVIDER_CONFIG = "user";
    }

    private Config config;

    public FactoryConfig(Config config) {
        this.config = config;
    }

    public String getUserProviderModuleClassName() {
        return config.getString(Keys.USER_PROVIDER_MODULE);
    }

    public Config getUserProviderConfig() {
        return config.getConfig(Keys.USER_PROVIDER_CONFIG);
    }
}
```

UserProvider.java

```
public class UserProvider implements IUserProvider {
    private UserProviderConfig config;
    private IDataSource dataSource;

    public UserProvider(UserProviderConfig config, IDataSource dataSource) {
        this.config = config;
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    @Override
    public void work() {
        System.out.println("UserProvider");
        dataSource.work();
    }
}
```

UserProviderConfig.java

```
public class UserProviderConfig {
    private interface Keys {
        String DATA_SOURCE_PROVIDER_MODULE = "dataSource.module";
        String DATA_SOURCE_PROVIDER_CONFIG = "dataSource";
    }

    private Config config;

    public UserProviderConfig(Config config) {
        this.config = config;
    }

    public String getDataSourceModuleClassName() {
        return config.getString(Keys.DATA_SOURCE_PROVIDER_MODULE);
    }

    public Config getDataSourceConfig() {
        return config.getConfig(Keys.DATA_SOURCE_PROVIDER_CONFIG);
    }
}
```

UserProviderModule.java

```
public class UserProviderModule extends PrivateModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
    }

    @Provides
    public UserProviderConfig userProviderConfig(FactoryConfig settings) {
        return new UserProviderConfig(settings.getUserProviderConfig());
    }

    @Provides
    @Exposed
    public IUserProvider userProvider(UserProviderConfig config, Injector injector) throws Exception {
        Injector childInjector = injector.createChildInjector((Module)Class.forName(config.getDataSourceModuleClassName()).newInstance());

        return new UserProvider(config, childInjector.getInstance(IDataSource.class));
    }
}
```

And then `DatabaseDataSource` and `LdapDataSource`, which aren't really important here, I think.

In practice, I have tested that the sub module injections work. However, I want to know if this is the recommended way to load plugins in a sub module.

I have seen recommendations that simply load `IDataSource` in the `Factory.create` method, but that means now the `Factory` must know that this `IDataSource` exist and must manage it. In theory, the `Factory` should only know about the top level providers that it cares about, eg only the `UserProvider` and let the `UserProvider` use DI to provision itself.

Comment: This seems like a complicated way for deciding what type of IDataSource to  provide based on the settings. You can achieve the same by using `@Named` annotation by providing the String value from the config and binding the IDataSource with annotation to appropriate implementation.

Comment: Yes, I find it very complicated as well. I am hoping there may be some people on SO who has a better way to share. I'll go try the @Name way and see if I could reduce the complexity